# Is there a more elegant way of switching templates based on the user-agent, in JSF?

Tags: jsf, browser, mobile, user-agent

We have a web application written with JSF and are trying to add a mobile version to it. Ideally, we'd have a separate folder with templates, CRUD and resources (e.g. jQuery Mobile) and our landing page would be able to choose the appropriate template based on the user-agent attribute of the header.

One way would be to use a scriptlet and redirect to mobile/index.xhtml - end of story, but people don't like scriptlets :D

Another way would be to wrap the content of the landing page (includind the templated parts) in a panelGroup with rendered="#{mobileDetector.isMobile()}", having a backing bean perform what the scriptlet would have done otherwise. But I think it kind of cripples the templates, plus it doesn't apply to the head section.

So - is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use a separate subdomain, e.g. mobile.example.com for mobile users and (www.)example.com for desktop users, and/or sniff the user agent. There are public APIs available on:

- http://user-agent-string.info
- http://www.useragentstring.com

Alternatively, you can use CSS to hide/change parts of the the HTML markup based on the [media type](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/desktop.css" media="screen,projection">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css" media="handheld">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" media="print">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/iphone.css" media="all and (max-device-width: 480px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ipad-portrait.css" media="all and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ipad-landscape.css" media="all and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)">
```

Comment: The thing is, there are major changes to the layouts, because some of them don't degrade gracefully (such as several jQuery plugins) and because we simply don't need all the features in the mobile version. Plus, mixing desktop/mobile content in the same page seems bad practice.

Comment: Your only resort is then using a separate subdomain and/or sniffing the UA.

Comment: so, more to the point, once I sniff the UA, then what? Where do I perform the actual switching?

Comment: Best place would be a filter. Let it redirect the response to the proper subdomain or page.

Comment: Or `@WebFilter` when you're on Servlet 3.0. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info